# Deserializing sets the contents of MainWindow in wpf to null

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization

I'm trying to deserialize the Opacity property of a border control in MainWindow

```
 public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Serialization.DeSerialize(this);
        }

  public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            info.AddValue("OffOpacity", Off.Opacity);
        }

        public MainWindow(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            Off.Opacity = (double)info.GetValue("OffOpacity", typeof(double));
        }
```

This is the deserializing method:

```
  public static void DeSerialize(MainWindow M)
        {
            try
            {   var binaryIO = new BinaryFormatter();
                using (Stream stream = File.Open(@"./History.dat", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    M = (MainWindow)binaryIO.Deserialize(stream);
                }
            }catch(Exception e) { }
           
        }
```

After **InitializeComponent();** I checked **Off** and it was not null. After **Serialization.DeSerialize(this);** runs and calls the constructor that gets the value, **Off** becomes null for some reason and gives me a nullreference error trying to get the value.

Comment: You're mixing state and data, and are using a reference which won't work like this (assigning M in another function won't affect the `this` you pass). Basically, your form is up and running after `InitializeComponent()`, it has a runtime state, and your deserialized form returned by `(MainWindow)binaryIO.Deserialize(stream)` hasn't got its `InitializeComponent()` called, so it has no instance in its `Off` member.

Comment: Are you saying that, when we set M equal to the deserialized form, the constructor that is run first, is not the one that executes InitializeComponent(); but the one that gets the value?

Comment: When deserializing, a constructor isn't run. You can't serialize forms like that.

Comment: public MainWindow(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) is run after we execute the deserializing method though, which gets the values from info and assigns them to the properties. Isn't that a constructor? Though, because It doesn't have InitializeComponent(); it gives me a nullreference. I assume I have to include that to fix the issue?

Comment: Yes, the BinaryFormatter invokes _that_ constructor on the instance it's deserializing, but that will not affect the MainWindow that you call `Serialization.DeSerialize(this)` from.

Comment: Right, it seems very tangled. I've read tutorials on how to do this, and most do Implement the iserializable interface, and then create a special constructor that gets the values from Info and is invoked when deserializing. It works just fine in classes, but if you said that it will not affect the MainWindow form that I call, how do I go on about loading the deserialized opacity property to the current form without it giving me a nullreference error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this exception because `Off` is a control, which is instantiated and configured (child properties being set) at runtime, through `InitializeComponent()`. The serializer creates a *new* instance of `MainWindow`, and calls the special `MainWindow(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)` constructor by convention.

Because that constructor doesn't call `InitializeComponent`, your `Off` control is `null`. The quick solution would be to change that constructor to:

```
public MainWindow(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Off.Opacity = (double)info.GetValue("OffOpacity", typeof(double));
}
```

Now your code runs, but the opacity isn't applied to your visible form, because it's applied to the instance created by the serializer. So you'll have to copy the properties of interest:

```
public static void DeSerialize(MainWindow m)
{
    try
    {
        var binaryIO = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(@"./History.dat", FileMode.Open))
        {
            var deserializedMainWindow = (MainWindow)binaryIO.Deserialize(stream);
            
            m.Off.Opacity = deserializedMainWindow.Off.Opacity;
            m.Other.Property = deserializedMainWindow.Other.Property;
            m.Foo.Bar = deserializedMainWindow.Foo.Bar;
            // ...
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) { }   
}
```

You probably can't even access those properties outside `MainWindow`, assuming they're not public, and you now have your property names all over the place.

There are libraries (Telerik for one) that can help serializing form layouts, without you having to specify over and over again which properties you're interested in. If you want to do it yourself and it's just a handful of properties, I'd suggest (de)serializing the appropriate layout into its own class:

```
public class MainWindowLayout
{
    public double? OffOpacity { get; set; }
    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }
    public bool? FooBar { get; set; }
}
```

And then in your form:

```
public void SerializeLayout()
{
    var layout = new MainWindowLayout
    {
        OffOpacity = Off.Opacity;
        OtherProperty = Other.Property;
        FooBar = Foo.Bar;
    };
    
    File.WriteAllText("MainWindowLayout.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(layout));
}

public void DeserializeLayout()
{
    // TODO: error handling and defaults
    var json = File.ReadAllText("MainWindowLayout.json");
    var layout = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainWindowLayout>(json);
    
    Off.Opacity = layout.OffOpacity;
    Other.Property = layout.OtherProperty;
    Foo.Bar = layout.FooBar;
}
```

If you don't want JSON but insist on BinaryFormatter, then adapt the code to support that.